# Problem when inserting data into SQL Compact by ADO.Net Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

```
        DatabaseEntities de = new DatabaseEntities();
        Income income = de.Incomes.CreateObject();            
        income.Id = de.Incomes.Max(f => f.Id) + 1;            
        income.Person = Users.SelectedValue.ToString();
        income.Value = value;
        income.Unit = Unit.SelectedValue.ToString();
        income.Description = Desc.Text;
        de.Incomes.AddObject(income);
        de.SaveChanges();
```

I have used the code section above to insert an Income object into SQL Compact database after that i have used the following statement to bind data to a DataGridView:

```
        IncomeGridView.DataSource = de.Incomes;
```

I saw the new data but after I closed my program I did not see the new data in table. Can anyone explain me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly this - http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/05/faq-why-does-my-changes-not-get-saved.html

Comment: Great help ErikEj! because I have used the SQL Compact so each time I debug my program the *.sdf file is copied to the Debug folder by default and my program work with the copy database. I resolved my problem by set the absolute path to the database file in the application config file.